# How to create a Dynamic link in Firebase programmatically? Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, url, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to create a firebase dynamic, but I can't get error in `components.shorten`

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Long link is not parsable.

I am following the firebase docs, but I can get the desired outcome.

```
 @IBAction func createGroupAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let dynamicLinkDomain = "https://a5481.app.goo.gl/"
    let appBundleID = "com.vividapartments.myStr.com"

    let params:[String : String] = [
        "ibi": appBundleID,
        "isi": "1222420082",
        "efr":"1",
        "groupID":"-LDSfWKKbWjyrXiFljT3",
        "chatID":"-LDSfWKMbm9mSE2a6EIe"
    ]

    // general link params
    let urlParams = params.flatMap ({ (key,value) -> String in
        return "\(key)=\(value)"
    }).joined(separator: "&")


    guard let deepLink = URL(string:"https://www.mystr.com/groups?\(urlParams)") else {return}

    print("deepLink is \(deepLink)")
    //prints:
    //deepLink is https://www.mystr.com/groups?isi=1222420082&chatID=-LDSfWKMbm9mSE2a6EIe&efr=1&ibi=com.vividapartments.myStr.com&groupID=-LDSfWKKbWjyrXiFljT3

    let components = DynamicLinkComponents(link: deepLink, domain: dynamicLinkDomain)

    let iOSParams = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: appBundleID)
    iOSParams.minimumAppVersion = "1.5"
    components.iOSParameters = iOSParams

    //1. Build the dynamic long link
    let longlLink = components.url
    print("The long link is \(longlLink!)")
    //prints:
     //The long link is https://https://a5481.app.goo.gl//?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Emystr%2Ecom%2Fgroups%3Fisi%3D1222420082%26chatID%3D%2DLDSfWKMbm9mSE2a6EIe%26efr%3D1%26ibi%3Dcom%2Evividapartments%2EmyStr%2Ecom%26groupID%3D%2DLDSfWKKbWjyrXiFljT3&ibi=com%2Evividapartments%2EmyStr%2Ecom&imv=1%2E5

    //Set the length of a short Dynamic Link
    let options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
    options.pathLength = .unguessable
    components.options = options

    //2. Or create a shortened dynamic link
    components.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
            //prints:
            //error is The operation couldn’t be completed. Long link is not parsable: https://https://a5481.app.goo.gl//?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Emystr%2Ecom%2Fgroups%3Fisi%3D1222420082%26chatID%3D%2DLDSfWKMbm9mSE2a6EIe%26efr%3D1%26ibi%3Dcom%2Evividapartments%2EmyStr%2Ecom%26groupID%3D%2DLDSfWKKbWjyrXiFljT3&ibi=com%2Evividapartments%2EmyStr%2Ecom&imv=1%2E5
            return
        }

        // TODO: Handle shortURL.
        print("shortURL is \(String(describing: shortURL))")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for including the output in the comments, that made it easy to spot the errors.

1. Only include the domain in the dynamic link domain, e.g. `let dynamicLinkDomain = "a5481.app.goo.gl"`
2. To test further: you can debug the long link by adding "&d=1" to the end of the long lin, and pasting it in to a browser.

Comment: hi I am facing the same error
please check the link below 
help me if you have a solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67019905/11468227